# null value after binning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

while transforming continuous variable to categorical variable using **pd.cut()** null value appears in 'age' column which is transformed form 'age_in_years' that doesn't have any null value. what is the solution here?

```
df['age_in_years']=df['age_in_days']/365
df.drop('age_in_days',inplace=True,axis=1)
bins=[0,35,60,100]
group=['young','middle_aged','senior']
df['age']=pd.cut(df['age_in_years'],bins,labels=group,right=True).astype('object')
```

now when i run `df.isnull().sum()` the age column shows null values
[image o/p of df.isnull().sum()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxJtV.png)

dataset : https://drive.google.com/file/d/11_qSL5tI1epiRcOzueYaMT-1GUiwAQvs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dataframe `df` so that one can reproduce the issue? Especially the rows that give problems, which are probably due to the fact that their `age_in_years` is outside the range [0, 100]

Comment: thanks some ages are beyond the range(0,100)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
bins=[-np.inf,0,35,60,100,np.inf]
df['age']=pd.cut(df['age_in_years'],bins,labels=group,right=True).astype('object')
```

This will diagnose the problem and also include values below 0 `(-inf, 0.0]` and above 100 `[100.0, inf)`

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs because five of your rows have `age_in_years` larger than 100, and since you established that the last bin ends at 100, these five rows will get a null value when constructing `age`.

You can adjust your code using a `float('inf')` as the upper bound of the last bin:

```
bins = [0, 35, 60, float('inf')]
group = ['young', 'middle_aged', 'senior']
df['age'] = pd.cut(df['age_in_years'], bins, labels=group, right=False).astype('object')
```